# How to transfer data between RS-422 and RS-485 ports?

Tags: serial, rs232

I'm relatively new to behaviors of serial ports such as RS-232, RS-422, and RS-485. I'm wondering how do you initiate data transmission between a system and a device connected to each other thru one of the 3 serial ports? For example, on a BACNet network, how does one initiate data transfer between 2 devices connected by serial cables.  Is this done thru software, or can be done thru commands inside a command line prompt? How do we do this in Ubuntu and Windows OS?

Comment: It's totally unclear what level of abstraction we are talking on. On the physical layer the transfer initiating by sending start bit on the line. On software level it is initiated by some `write` command or similar.

Comment: I'd like to know both physical and software level. There are various applications such as Building Automation for a device I'm working on. RS-485 will be part of a BACNet for example

Comment: It is too broad. Try asking specific questions.

Comment: And when you properly split up the questions in this post, you will find that EE.SE will not give the same level and quality of answers about your software layer that StackOverflow would, so you're better off making different posts in different places anyway

Answer (score 4):

At its simplest level, both RS-422 and RS-485 are extensions of RS-232.  You can think of them as an RS-232 extension cord.  It is possible to buy a USB to RS-485 converter for your PC, which is just like a USB to RS-232 converter except it as a different electrical interface.

The big difference between the them is that RS-232 uses single-end cabling, and RS-422 and RS-485 use differential cabling, which allows for much greater cable lengths (4000 ft for RS-422 and RS-485, vs 50 ft for RS-232 -- although many people run RS-232 cables longer than that).  Data rates for RS-422 and RS-485 are considerably higher than RS-232 also.

RS-422 and RS-485 also allow a master-slave network to be set up.  RS-422 does not tri-state their transmitters, whereas RS-485 does, so RS-485 can have more nodes -- 32 drivers and 32 receiver vs 1 driver and 10 for receivers RS-422.  Otherwise they are essentially the same.  In fact, since they have the same voltage levels, you can put RS-422 receivers on a RS-485 network with some restrictions.

[image]

RS-422 and RS-485 do not specify any particular protocol, unlike RS-232 which has a specific protocol that is familiar to almost any programmer.  As a result, it is possible to use the regular RS-232 protocol over an RS-422 and RS-485 interface, as long as there are only two nodes.  If there are multiple nodes, then there has to be a method of addressing which slave is to be addressed.  One can layer the addressing scheme on top of RS-232 if desired,or use another protocol (addressing is all done in software, not hardware).

If one is already using RS-232 in their program, and want to use a RS-485 on a two node network, there are no changes necessary.

If you have installed an RS-422 or RS-485 interface with Windows, there should be drivers that allow you to talk to the interface directly (unless you are using a USB to RS-422/RS-485 cable as mentioned earlier, and then the cable would appear as a COM port just like RS-232).

[BACnet MS/TP](http://www.bacnet.org/Bibliography/BACnet-Today-10/Karg_2010.pdf) (Master-Slave/Token-Passing.) devices use RS-485 as their physical layer.  Addressing is done using 8-bit MAC addresses, often configured on the slave device using a DIP switch.  If you have installed BACNet software on your machine, there should be a way for it to take advantage of the installed RS-485 drivers.

Since BACNet is designed for RS-485, there should be commands built into it to perform a data transfer between two devices by first specifying the MAC ID of the slave and then initiate the data transfer.  Check your documentation.